# SQL COUNT() and Angular

Tags: mysql, angular, count

I have a problem to display my SQL command (Count()) with Angular.

PHP file (No problem with this file) :

```
$app->get('/animal/{idA}/nb', function ($idA) use ($app) {
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as nbTotal FROM animal WHERE idAnimal = :idA;
$animalCount = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql, array('idA' => (int) $idA));

 return json_encode($animalCount); });
```

But to display it with Angular :

animal.service.ts

```
getNbAnimals(idA: number){ return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/animal/' + idA + '/nb'); }
```

animal.component.ts

```
 getNbAnimals(idA: number){ this.animalService.getNbAnimals(idA); }
```

animal.component.html

```
<p>{{getNbAnimals(idAnimal.value)}}</p>
```

The result of this HTML file is [object Object]. I don't know how to display my COUNT().
If you can help me, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

That's because your trying to display what that function returns, which is normally an observable. Instead try with :

```
<p>{{getNbAnimals(idAnimal.value) | async}}</p>
```

---

**Or** `subscribe` on that service in the TS part :

```
 getNbAnimals(idA: number){ 

    return this.animalService.getNbAnimals(idA)
           .subscribe((response)=> return response);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  I tried async and subscribe but the console of my browser displays errors one by one every seconds and I can't display the 'nbTotal'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an object returned by

```
 this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/animal/' + idA + '/nb');
```

So just do extra step before return

```
 phpObj = this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/animal/' + idA + '/nb');
 //and then return object property value
 return phpObj.nbTotal;
```

Or you can fix your php response to return just value but not array:

```
 return json_encode($animalCount['nbTotal']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! For the first, the TS file doesn't "know"  nbTotal. An the second does the same the same problem. I don't know how to convert the Object return to a simple number return.

Comment: I suspect just on php side change return to: `return $animalCount['nbTotal'];`

Comment: @Thomas check this article: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-get-example#http-get